# unwanted vertical space between <div> tags caused by <hx> tag

Tags: html

Maybe this has been discussed here before, but I was unable to find a related post. So here is my problem:

I have a html site with a banner and a content area. The banner area has a border at the bottom:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #banner, #content {
            width: 1000px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }
        #content {
            background-color: green;
        }
        #banner {
            background-color: red;
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
            height: 70px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="banner">
        <h3>Banner</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h3>Content</h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is the horizontal whitespace between the banner and the content div (which I don't want).

However, if I move the `border-bottom` from the banner div to a `border-top` of the content div the whitespace dissapears and everything is rendered as I would have expected it. This seems strange to me, but is at least consistent between chrome and ie9 (haven't tested other browsers yet). What is the reason for this behaviour? It seems that is caused by the h3 tag. Note also, that the page height varies depending on the positon of the border.

Comment: remove all padding and margin from the h3

Comment: @DickieBoy: Thanks, but why does the margin and padding change in dependence of the position of the border? (I try to understand the problem...)

Comment: Have a look at this page on collapsing margins:
[http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be the margin of the h elements. Do `h3{margin:0px;}` That should sort the gap :)

EDIT :

If the gap persists try padding on the h elements too. 
Or the error could be with the margin between the banner and content.

Comment: Thanks Bento. Do you have an idea, why the margin changes depending on where I place the border? It seems to me like an inconsistent way of how the html is rendered.

Comment: h1,h2,h3,p,span,iframe,a,body,html and possibly a many others will always have default paddings and margins which vary between element and browser types. I've been caught out a few times myself. With divs, to my knowledge they don't have default paddings and margins BUT the elements stated above can effect the positioning of other elements. Not really sure why to be honest lol might be something to do with the structure and z-index of each elements but don't hold me to that. Anything else let me know :)

Comment: Thanks Bento. The strange thing is, that the margin doesn't vary between browsers (this may be also true), but between the position of the border (if I place the border on the bottom of the banner I see the whitespace, if I place the border at the top of the content I don't)

Comment: Not sure why that is :S try removing the width, margin-right and left and try this for the banner and content element.
width: 80%;
margin:0% 9% 0% 10%;

Comment: @Bento checkout the link i put in the comments of the OP

Comment: @DickieBoy Yea I gave it a quick skim. But I've alway found that to look at the box model helps understand where the paddings and margins are being applied and what they can effect. forgot the link [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

Comment: @Bento Yes that link shows how the box model works, the problem the OP  had was to do with collapsing margins, that article does a good job of explaining it.

Comment: @DickieBoy Sorry I understand the concept now sorry.

Answer (score 0):

to every browser has its own implementation of HTMl tags. All the HTML elements have their own margin and padding values depending on the browser
It is a good practice to reset all the elements in margin and padding values to "0". then your styling values of margin and padding reflect exactly.

declare the below in the starting of you css.

*{ margin:0px; padding:0px;}

Comment: Thanks for your response. The question was more of a "why is that", than of a "how to fix" kind. DickieBoy has posted a link which explains the described behaviour (that was exactly what I was looking for).